# Using Response In Further Function

Tags: javascript

```
 function tinyurl(){
     jQuery.ajax({
         url:'http://tinyurl.com/api-create.php?url=http://xxxxxxxxxxx/',
         dataType:'script',
         success:function(response){
             var tiny = response.id;
         }
     });
 }


function wal(){
   jQuery.ajax({
       url:'Http://xxxxx.xx/xxx' + tiny +',
       dataType:'jsonp',
       success:function(data){
       }
   });
}
```

Please Help Me I Want to Use that tiny url in frnd function

I am not getting any success Please Help me.

I want to use that response.id In wal function .

Comment: You should return a promise.

Comment: You got an error on `url:'Http://xxxxx.xx/xxx' + tiny +',`

Comment: Look at the syntax highlighting... you have an unmatched quote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two steps:

1. Edit your `wal()` function to take a parameter:

   ```
   function wal(tiny) {
   ```
2. In `tinyurl`'s success function, call `wal()`, passing the response id to it:

   ```
   function tinyurl() {
       jQuery.ajax({
           url: 'http://tinyurl.com/api-create.php?url=http://xxxxxxxxxxx/',
           dataType: 'script',
           success: function (response) {
               wal(response.id);
           }
       });
   }
   ```

Comment: function wal(tiny) {   or function wal(tinyurl) {    ?

Comment: I used `tiny` because you have the following in your `wal()` function: `url:'Http://xxxxx.xx/xxx' + tiny`. The reference is not to an existing variable but to what you are passing whenever the function is called. In this case, the value of `tiny` in that function will be the same as the value of `response.id` in the other function.